# SQL Server 2008 R2 Convert varbinary to readable text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to get the contents of the file in a `varbinary` column I store such as .doc and .pdf file. I can successfully read the .txt inserted while the pdf and doc is not readable

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(Docs, 3, LEN(DOCS)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
    ID, fileextension
FROM 
    dbo.documents 
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(docs, 'brand')
```

Comment: You have to store somewhere part of text from file for searching purposes then..

Comment: You need to use BCP and save the content as a file to disk.

Comment: Yes exactly I need to select some part of .doc/.pdf file readable text maybe the 1st 500 characters inside the file

Comment: @IvanStarostin how do i store some part of the text from the file can you please tell me how

Comment: Actually this is not an sql-question. Process your files with background service which reads these files and posts searchable text back to DB.